# Possible to create a new post and have the Title and Slug automatically use the post's ID?

Tags: slug, title, id

For a given Custom Post Type, I'd like that every time I create a new post (by using the Dashboard, clicking the button "Add new"), that the slug and Title assume this post's ID.

I belive that the ID is only assigned when the post is saved (draft or published), and the slug is only assigned when the status is published... so, how could I accoplish this?

The reason is simple : the custom post types are to be anonymous, and the post ID was the simplest approach I could think of, but I'm open to alternatives.

Comment: @prosti I fail to see how the short answers above do anything to help me solve this...

Comment: There may be more @Jean-FrancoisArseneault questions you may ask, but  I provided you one possible answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `ID` for the `post_title` and `post_name`. You have many approaches.

Typically your approach would be to use a filter in WordPress. The best I can say would be `wp_insert_post_data` and use the second parameter of this filter to get the post id and return the first parameter with the modified `post_title` and `post_name`.

The other option would be to use actions either `save_post` or `wp_insert_post`

They are defined with the same arguments.

```
File: wp-includes/post.php
3496:   /**
3497:    * Fires once a post has been saved.
3498:    *
3499:    * @since 1.5.0
3500:    *
3501:    * @param int     $post_ID Post ID.
3502:    * @param WP_Post $post    Post object.
3503:    * @param bool    $update  Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
3504:    */
3505:   do_action( 'save_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );
3506: 
3507:   /**
3508:    * Fires once a post has been saved.
3509:    *
3510:    * @since 2.0.0
3511:    *
3512:    * @param int     $post_ID Post ID.
3513:    * @param WP_Post $post    Post object.
3514:    * @param bool    $update  Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
3515:    */
3516:   do_action( 'wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );
```

This may be from where you can start. Note that using `wp_update_post` at the end of `_20170104_02` function will fire our `save_post` action again, so we needed to remove that action to escape from the infinite loop.

If you would use `wp_insert_post_data` this would not be needed, since filters return the data.

```
add_action('save_post', '_20170104_02', 10, 3);

function _20170104_02( $post_id, $post, $update ){

    if ( 'cpt' != $post->post_type) // only for your custom post type cpt
        return;

    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    if ( wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) )
        return;

    if ( !( true == $update  && 'publish' == $post->post_status ) )
        return;

    remove_action( 'save_post', '_20170104_02' );

    $my_post = array(
          'ID'           => $post_id,
          'post_title'   => $post_id,
          'post_name'    => $post_id
    );

    wp_update_post( $my_post );
}
```