# Auto Slug Generation for Custom Post type

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

Is there any way to generate slug for custom post type in alphabetical order or use first few words from the content of the post?

This is because I have created a custom post type that does not have any title. Only content, categories, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [**save_post**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook. For example if you have a custom post type **stack**, the hook can be changed to **save_post_stack**.

To set the post-slug to the first few words of the content:

```
add_action( 'save_post_stack', 'wpse251743_set_title', 10, 3 );
function wpse251743_set_title ( $post_id ){
    //This temporarily removes action to prevent infinite loops
    remove_action( 'save_post_stack', 'wpse251743_set_title' );

    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    $post_content = $post->post_content;

    //GET THE FIRST THREE WORDS
    $words = array_slice(str_word_count( $post_content, 2), 0, 5);

    $post_name = implode(' ', $words );

    //update title
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID'        => $post_id,
        'post_name' =>  $post_name, //Wordpress would generate the slug based on the post name
    ));

    //redo action
    add_action( 'save_post_stack', 'wpse251743_set_title', 10, 3 );
}
```

> **Avoiding infinite loops:**
>
> If you are calling a function such as
>   **`wp_update_post`** that includes the **`save_post`** hook, your hooked function
>   will create an infinite loop. To avoid this, unhook your function
>   before calling the function you need, then re-hook it afterward.

Comment: That did a trick. Cheers..

Comment: Don't forget to upvote :)

Comment: @TunjiAyoola, `save_post_...` is not a filter but the action hook. Please improve.

Comment: Do you really need to remove the action add the action @TunjiAyoola inside? I think no.

Comment: Yes you do: According to the codex; If you are calling a function such as wp_update_post that includes the save_post hook, your hooked function will create an infinite loop. To avoid this, unhook your function before calling the function you need, then re-hook it afterward.

Comment: @TunjiAyoola, thanks mate it was a trick question. Upvote.

Comment: @TunjiAyoola I had the similar [problem](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251179/possible-to-create-a-new-post-and-have-the-title-and-slug-automatically-use-the/251293#251293)